# Deleting an Object from Collection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am storing a bunch of patent data in a MySQL database and interacting with it via SQLAlchemy.  I have a collection inside the Patent class that represents the list of assignees (the companies that were assigned the patent):

```
assignees = relationship('Company', secondary=patent_company_table, backref='patents')
```

I am processing some of the objects stored in the database and for a Patent object `p`, I want to delete some assignee `a` (a Company object) from `p`'s assignee list.  Based off of http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#deleting-from-collections , it seems that calling `s.delete(a)` will actually delete the Company object `a`.  I simply want to remove assignee `a` from the list of assignees for `p` (i.e. remove a row in the patent_company_table), NOT actually delete the Company object, because `a` might be in another Patent object's list of assignees.

I tried creating a new list `new_assignees` that only includes the assignees from `p` besides `a` and then called:

```
p.assignees = new_assignees
s.add(p)
```

This unfortunately does not actually mark `p` as dirty, so I assume it would not affect the database.

Do you have any suggestions for how to remove an object from the collection, deleting the row in the patent_company_table as opposed to deleting the object from the Company table?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
assignees = patent.assignees
for assignee in assignees:
    if assignee in duplicate_company_to_default:
        patent.assignees.remove(assignee)
        default_company = duplicate_company_to_default[assignee]
        if default_company not in assignees:
            added_patent_count += 1
            patent.assignees.append(default_company)
```

After looping through all of the patents, `added_patent_count = 983672` but there are no objects in `session.dirty()`.  Do I need to add manually to the session after modifying via `append` or `remove`?

Comment: Would you be able to extract and post the working sample script for this issue (model definition, sample duplicate dict etc)? Also wondering what type of `PrimaryKey` identifiers are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQLAlchemy collections support list-like append/remove operations.

```
p.assignees.remove(c)
```

This should remove `c` form `p.assignees` without deleting `c` from database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not solve the problem.  I included a code snippet above.

Comment: This works correctly.  The length of s.dirty is 0, but s.commit() still makes the necessary changes to the assignees relationship.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, this *will* remove the object from the database if you have cascade set to all, delete, delete-orphan, etc.

Answer (score 7):

a working sample script means, we can run it fully.  Here's a script generated from the snippets you've given.   The one thing that helps is to evaluate "assignees" as a list, since you are removing from it, it's likely you're not iterating correctly.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base= declarative_base()

patent_company_table = Table('pct', Base.metadata,
    Column('patent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('patent.id')),
    Column('company_id', Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'))
)

class Patent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "patent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    assignees = relationship('Company', secondary=patent_company_table, backref='patents')

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

e = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)
p = Patent()
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = Company(), Company(), Company(), Company(), Company()
d1, d2 = Company(), Company()
duplicate_company_to_default = {c1:d1, c2:d2, c3:d1, c4:d2}

new_assignees = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]
p.assignees = new_assignees
s.add(p)
s.commit()

patent = s.query(Patent).first()
assignees = patent.assignees
added_patent_count = 0
for assignee in list(assignees):
    if assignee in duplicate_company_to_default:
        patent.assignees.remove(assignee)
        default_company = duplicate_company_to_default[assignee]
        if default_company not in assignees:
            added_patent_count += 1
            patent.assignees.append(default_company)

assert p in s.dirty

s.commit()

assert set(p.assignees) == set([d1, d2, c5])
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this up zzzeek.  It illustrates the relationship well.  I appreciate your help.