# Removing/Adding an Object from a Collection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oop, database-design, sqlalchemy

Issue at hand: Removing a User from Group and adding User to a Group
Many-to-One table Relationship
    *(Many Users to One Group)*

Using: SQLAlchemy 1.0.9, Python 2.7.9

DB operates off of `CRUD` operations: 
1. Create a group (e.g. 'admin')
2. Retrieve group (*using either group name or id*)
3. **Update:**

   a) Update : **add_user** to group ('joe' to 'admin')
   b) Update : **remove_user** from group ('bob' from 'editor')
4. Delete group

I am a newbie trying to get my hands dirty, but smartly here. 
1. I am attempting to remove a `.user` from `Group()` in the function: `update_remove_user` without deleting the `user` from `User()`. I found something similar to what I want to do on Stacks [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378468/deleting-an-object-from-collection-in-sqlalchemy) and in the [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html?highlight=delete%20collections#dynamic-relationship-loaders)
2. Adding a user to an existing group. Right now, the function is creating a group and user instead of retrieving a group and adding the user to it.

model: base.py

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    modified_on = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow) #new

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship('User', backref='groups')

   def __init__(self, group_name, *args):
       self.group_name = group_name
       self.args = args

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Group(group_name='%s')>" % (self.group_name)
```

object.py

```
def create_group(self, group_name): 
    new_group = Group(group_name)
    self.session.add(new_group)
    self.session.commit()
    return new_group
    print 'this is the new group: ', new_group

def update_group_add_user(self, group_name, user):
    g = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.group_name == group_name).one()
    if g:
        g.append(user) # append not found
        self.session.commit()

def update_group_remove_user(self, group_name, user):
    remove_user = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.group_name == group_name).\
    filter(Group.user == user).one()
    if remove_user:
        r = remove_user.user
        print 'test r : ', r
        g = Group() # does not work 
        g.remove(r)
        self.session.commit()
```

---

**Changes per suggestions below:**
Works except `add_user` REPLACES a `user` with `new user` when added to the SAME group (as indicated by Alex) with a Many-to-One relationship. So added a Many-to-Many relationship and the same issue is occurring. A user is being replace with another in the many-to-many relationship.

Changes are reflected with **#** below of working code that has resolved the issues.Code is working for a N-N relationship.

object.py

```
def update_group_add_user(self, group_name, user):
    g = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.group_name == group_name).one()
    if g:
        found_name = g.group_name
        g.users = [user] # < replaced with working: g.users.append(user)
        print 'found_name and user: ', found_name, user
        self.session.commit()

def update_group_remove_user(self, group_name, user):
    remove_user = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.group_name == group_name).one()
    if remove_user:
        remove_user.users = None # < replaced with working remove_user.users.remove(user)
        self.session.commit()
```

New **Many to Many** design:

```
association_t = Table('group_user_link', Base.metadata,
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id')),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')))

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    user = relationship('User', secondary='group_user_link', backref='groups')

    # more...

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(40), unique=True)
    # more info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that you want create Many-to-One relationship?

According to this relationship one "group" can contain only one user. This is something opposite to term "group". I think, you should create [Many-to-Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) relationship.

As for your first issue:

```
g = self.session.query(Group).\
filter(Group.group_name == group_name).one()
...
g.append(user) # append not found
```

When you make such query, the result is an instance of `Group` class. And this instance doesn't have `append` method. The right way to change user for this group is:

```
g.user = user
```

As for the second issue:

```
def update_group_remove_user(self, group_name, user):
    remove_user = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.group_name == group_name).\
    filter(Group.user == user).one()
    if remove_user:
        r = remove_user.user
        print 'test r : ', r
        g = Group() # does not work 
        g.remove(r)
        self.session.commit()
```

Again, `remove_user` is an instance of `Group` now (so, you have chosen wrong name for it).

When you tried `g = Group(); g.remove(r)` you just created new instance of `Group` and tried to call method which doesn't exists. So, in order to delete this user from the group you should:

```
remove_user.user = None
self.session.commit()
```

Comment: SEE ABOVE : Now a many-to-many table format with traceback error

Comment: Initially I wanted (as shown above): Many-to-One table Relationship where
Many Users to One Group so that user1 could not belong to 2 or more groups.

Comment: Try `remove_user.users.remove(user)`

Comment: The `_add_user` method keeps replacing users and not adding a user. `remove_user.users.remove(user)` works!

Comment: Never mind, I used something similar to your recommendation: `g.users.append(user)` the `append` method works now. I am getting multiple adds for the same group.  Thank you for all your help Alexsandr!